# How not to make <br> a tag

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
  var y="<br>"
  function repeater(num){
    for (var i=0;i<num;i++)
      {document.write(y) }
  }

  document.write(repeater(4))


</script>
```

My goal is to make the tag appear
4 times, not the actual breaks. The result shows undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
  var res = "";
  var y="<br>";
  function repeater(num){
    for (var i=0;i<num;i++) {
        res = res + y;
    }
    $('#customDiv').text(res);
}
(repeater(4))
```

You can put a custom `<div id="customDiv"></div>` inside your html file.

Answer (score 2):

Since the question is asking for Javascript solution not JQuery (since no jQuery tags), I'll add the answer using Javascript.

```js
<script>
    var y = "<br>"

    function repeater(num) {
        for (var i=0; i < num; i++) {
            document.body.innerText += y;
        }
    }

    repeater(4);
</script>
```

or maybe you need to set a text into the spesific element (`<div id="app"><div>`)? no problem, we can improve the code a little bit.

```js
<script>
    var y = "<br>"

    function repeater(el, num) {
        for (var i=0; i < num; i++) {
            el.innerText += y;
        }
    }

    var el = document.getElementById('app');
    repeater(el, 4);
</script>
```

Comment: since you seem to want to improve the original code, you can also notice that no need for for loop:```el.innerText = y.repeat(num)``` is enough

Comment: @user753642 No, I'm not improve the original code. I just want to add JS solution, not jQuery solution.

Comment: oh did not see accepted answered contained jquery, my bad